# Proving that a subspace of a normed vector space is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Question: Let X be a normed vector space.
If M is a closed subspace of X and x ∈ X − M then M + ℂx is closed
where M + ℂx = { y + λ x : y ∈ M , λ ∈ ℂ }

There's a theorem from Folland's Real Analysis ensuring the existence of an $f\in X^*$ with $\|f\|=1$, $f=0$ on $M$, and $$f(x)=\inf_{y\in M}\|x-y\|:=\delta$$
Since its continuous, can I look at the set $f(M+\mathbb{C}x)$, see that its just $\mathbb{C}\delta$ which is closed since $\mathbb{C}$ is, hence its pre-image must be, by the continuity of f?

Comment: Well, there's a bit of a problem: $\delta$ is not a vector in $X$, but a (positive) number, so $\Bbb C\delta=\Bbb C.$ Its preimage is all of $X,$ which doesn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

By the theorem you've quoted, there is an $f\in X^{\ast}$ with $f|_M=0$, $||f||=1$ and $$f(x)=\inf_{y\in M}|x-y|=\delta$$ for $x\not\in M$. Let $z_n=y_n+c_nx\in M+\Bbb Cx$ be a sequence which converges to $z\in X$. By continuity, $f(z_n)\to f(z)$. Now, $f(z_n)=f(y_n)+c_nf(x)=c_n\delta$. This implies that $c_n\delta\to f(z)$, so $c_n$ converges to $c=\frac{f(z)}{\delta}$. So, $z_n$ converges, and $c_n$ converges, we have that $y_n=z_n-c_nx$ is the difference of two convergent sequences, and thus converges. But since $y_n\in M$, $M$ is closed, this implies $y_n\to y\in M$. Thus, $z_n=y_n+c_nx\to y+cx\in M+\Bbb Cx$. So $M+\Bbb Cx$ is closed.

Comment: thats a very nice solution. does that mean mine is wrong? just to help my understanding, would you be able to point out where I went wrong?

Comment: You want to say that $f^{-1}(\Bbb C\delta)=M+\Bbb C x$. But, all you know to start with is $M+\Bbb C x\subset f^{-1}(\Bbb C\delta)$. You don't know that the kernel of $f$ is $M$, just that $M$ is in the kernel.

Comment: I don't know that this approach will work to be honest. Topology is powerful because of its generality, but using the most general definition of continuity is going to be difficult because you know so little about the function $f$. This is further made difficult because $f^{-1}(\Bbb C\delta)=X$, which, yes, is closed, but not helpful for what you want to prove.